# Cannot Make Sense of How Local and Global Variable Work

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

As a new python learner, I really appreciate your advice why my understanding about the following case is wrong:

When I wrote code as follows:

```py
class Solution(object):

    def isHappy(self, n):
        seen = {}
        while n!=1 and n not in seen.keys():
            seen[n] = '*'
            n = self.get_next(n)
        return n==1

    total_sum = 0
    def get_next(self,no):

        while no>0:
            no,v = divmod(no,10)
            total_sum+=v**2
        return total_sum
test55 = Solution()
test55.isHappy(56)
```

But it throws me the error saying "local variable 'total_sum' referenced before assignment", I think it should work because: although we didn't initialize total_sum inside get_next function, I expect it should look for total_sum outside of the function. Could anyone share some advice why I'm wrong?

If we put total_sum inside get_next function, then it works:

```py
class Solution(object):

    def isHappy(self, n):
        seen = {}
        while n!=1 and n not in seen.keys():
            seen[n] = '*'
            n = self.get_next(n)
        return n==1


    def get_next(self,no):
        total_sum = 0
        while no>0:
            no,v = divmod(no,10)
            total_sum+=v**2
        return total_sum
test55 = Solution()
test55.isHappy(56)
```

Comment: `self.total_sum += v**2` & `return self.total_sum`

Comment: In the first case `total_sum` it is not a global variable, but class property. To access to this property you need to use `self.total_sum `. Also you can remove indentation and put this variable to upper context